# F# struct declaration with private constructor

Tags: f#

Suppose we have an AngularSpeed class that holds Angle, Speed and Time (Speed = Angle/Time). Obviously, it is ambiguous to set all three values at a time. So we use private constructor and static functions to create AngularSpeed from (Speed, Time) or (Angle, Time)

```
[<Struct>]
type AngularSpeed private (angle: float, speed: float, time: float) =

    member x.Angle = angle
    member x.Time = time
    member x.Speed = speed

    static member FromAngleTime(angle, time) = AngularSpeed(angle, angle/time, time)
    static member FromSpeedTime(speed, time) = AngularSpeed(time*speed, speed, time)
```

The example works. But I was unable to create the same structure without [Struct] but with ''struct ... end'' keywords. So, how to make the same structure with ''struct ... end''? Is it possible?

```
type AngularSpeed  =
    struct
      ...
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the `struct...end` syntax used much, but a direct reformulation would look like this (the name for this type is strange, see below):

```
type AngularSpeed =
    struct
        val Angle : float
        val Speed : float
        val Time : float
    end

    private new (angle, speed, time) =
        { Angle = angle; Speed = speed; Time = time }

    static member FromAngleTime(a, t) = AngularSpeed(a, a/t, t)
    static member FromSpeedTime(s, t) = AngularSpeed(s*t, s, t)
```

Note that no matter the syntax, any struct like this will have an empty constructor that sets all values to `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`.

### Approach variant

This structure stores data redundantly; angle could be a member. Also, you are using physical units; you might want to use units of measure. As is, I do not understand what this type is. I would not expect an angular velocity to contain a time or angle at all, rather it would be a `float</s>`, or a `float<deg/s>` if you prefer angles in degrees. Maybe this type should be called `RotationProcess` or something similar?

```
/// Time in seconds. Abbreviation for the Microsoft standardized type.
[<Measure>] type s = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitSymbols.s

type RotationProcess =
    struct
        val Speed : float</s>
        val Time : float<s>
    end

    member rp.Angle = rp.Speed * rp.Time
    private new (s, t) = { Speed = s; Time = t }
    static member FromAngleTime(a, t) = RotationProcess(a/t, t)
    static member FromSpeedTime(v, t) = RotationProcess(v, t)
    static member FromAngleSpeed(a, v) = RotationProcess(v, a/v)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that definition using `[<Struct>]` and primary constructor is generally preferred (at least, it looks nicer to me!) but I believe the following definition using `struct .. end` is equivalent to what you're doing:

```
type AngularSpeed = struct
  val mutable angle : float
  val mutable speed : float
  val mutable time : float
  private new (angle: float, speed: float, time: float) =
    { angle = angle; time = time; speed = speed }
  static member FromAngleTime(angle, time) = AngularSpeed(angle, angle/time, time)
  static member FromSpeedTime(speed, time) = AngularSpeed(time*speed, speed, time)
end
```

I guess the trickiest thing is the syntax for the constructor body - rather than assigning the values using mutation, F# uses record-like syntax to initialize the fields.